# Checking a list of words in a column

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I have the following code in tidyverse and list of words in words.xlsx like:
  hello
  world
  program
  data
  analysis

```
v1 = read_excel('words.xlsx') %>% 
     mutate(words = tolower(words))%>%
     pull(1)
for(v in v1){
data1 = data1 %>%
mutate(!! v := as.integer(heading %like% v))
}
```

I want to edit this code, so that instead of an integer, I get the actual words which were found in every string (separated with a comma) like in the image[image]

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example and show expected output based on that?

Comment: It adds a column but has duplicates as well for e.g. hello, hello, world

Comment: You should add that information with all such edge cases in the example. I have updated the answer to get only unique values. Also you should not share data using image, see here on how to give reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I tried to repeat the process to get another column using v2, I get an error: Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: I have not used `mutate` anywhere in my answer, I don't know how did you get that as an error.

Comment: I made some edit mutate    ```(L1 = sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(data1$heading, 
                                paste0('\\b', v1, '\\b', collapse = '|')), 
                                function(x) toString(unique(x))))
  mutate(L2 = sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(data1$heading, 
                                paste0('\\b', v2, '\\b', collapse = '|')), 
                                function(x) toString(unique(x)))) ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214580/discussion-between-trex-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: can you help me relax the word boundaries...so when I search for 'fox', it should hit 'foxx' and 'xxfox' and 'xxfoxa' as well

Comment: you can remove `\\b` from `paste0`, i.e `sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(data1$heading, paste0(v1,collapse = '|')), function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Comment: I tried that and it works. However, in many cases it could not catch 'ai' even when the word 'retail' was present. Not sure what am I missing

Comment: Also I noticed that if I have the word 'data' is the list then 'data science' is getting dropped in the process of making a unique list of words. Any idea?

Comment: It will be better to post as a new question with relevant sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste all the words in `v1` with word boundaries and use `str_extract_all` to extract any word in `v1` present in `data1$heading`. `str_extract_all` would return list of words, we can use `sapply` to get them as one concatenated string.

```
sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(data1$heading, 
    paste0('\\b', v1, '\\b', collapse = '|')), function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```